# SSRS configuration

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I installed SSRS on my computer with the file SSDTBI_x86_ENU.exe. I started to create a report server project which contain tow .rdl file. Now I want to deploy it so I can see my reports in the browser. When I click the start button Visual studio give me an error and say that I have to specify a valid URL. So I went to reporting services configuration manager. My problem is when I enter my server name it says invalid namespace!!

Comment: the deploy destination and browser UI are at different URL's. You usually deploy to http://../reportserver and browse at http://../reports

Comment: Well I tried to enter to the reporting configuration to change the url but when i enter my server name i get an error that says "invalid namespace". Some tutorial pointed that it may be a WMI error, i followed this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fa35a1f9-9fc6-4ba1-868b-0f53ae6e72b0/ssrs-2008-configuration-manager-invalid-class?forum=sqlreportingservices but could not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite taking -2 for this question, I will answer it because I resolve it and hope that will help somebody someday. It is a problem connected to the version of SQL server express with tools. It didn't allow the deployement of rapports. So I uninstall it and install sql server express with advanced services and every thing magically worked.